# Show category meta in loop on homepage

Tags: categories, meta-query

I'm working on a site that groups content into 'issues' using categories. The home page shows the latest issue by pulling the category with the highest ID (thus the most recent).

What I want to do is to also show the category title and description before the posts in that category loop below. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php $issue = get_terms('category', 'orderby=ID&order=DESC&number=1&child_of=3'); $latest_issue = $issue[0]->term_taxonomy_id; ?>
                <?php query_posts(array( 'category__in' => $latest_issue )); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                    <header class="home-header">

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a>

                    </header> <!-- end article header -->

                    <section class="home-content clearfix">

                        <div class="home-content-header"><h1 class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <span><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></h1></div>

                        <section class="post_content home-excerpt clearfix">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </section>

                </article> <!-- end article -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$category = get_category($latest_issue); // it is category object
echo $category->title;
echo $category->description;
```

in codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

But i think you should get category not by last created ID, but by slug:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug

So you should change:

```
  <?php $issue = get_terms('category', 'orderby=ID&order=DESC&number=1&child_of=3'); $latest_issue = $issue[0]->term_taxonomy_id; ?>
  <?php query_posts(array( 'category__in' => $latest_issue )); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $issue_category = get_category_by_slug('issue'); ?>
<?php query_posts(array( 'category__in' => $issue_category->term_id )); ?>
```

and to print your category title and description:

```
echo $issue_category->title;
echo $issue_category->description;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for getting the category by last created ID is that I need to show the most recent category of a particular child (an issue) and by sorting them numerically I can do this as the ID will always increase. My assumption is that I cannot do this by slug, but I may be wrong. I also tried echoing the category information but it's showing nothing unfortunately.